# StringBuilder corrupted (internal field `count` = 0)

Tags: java, mockito, stringbuilder, junit5

I write test for method which prints some output via some `writer`. `Writer` is just interface which implementation `ConsoleWriterImpl` is just wrapper for `System.out`.

**Goal of the test:** check that all info that should be printed has been passed to the `Writer.printLine(Object str)`.

**Problem**

I use `ArgumentCaptor<Object> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Object.class);` for capturing input to `Writer.printLine(Object str)`. Then get all inputs: `List outputList = argument.getAllValues();`.

That list consists of 2 types objects: Strings and StringBuilders. Then I want to convert all these objects to a one string in testing purposes. But all StringBuilders in `outputList` corrupted — they have [`count`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#49) = 0. So, when I try to convert these StringBuilders I got empty strings. *See below code of the test — I left comment where is problem.*

**Questions:**

- **Why StringBuilders got corrupted here?** If the reason is "*Instances of StringBuilder are not safe for use by multiple threads.*"([source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)) — please explain how it influences in that case, I don't create threads manually...
- **How to deal with it?**

---

**`ConsoleWriterImpl`**

```
public class ConsoleWriterImpl implements Writer {
    private PrintStream stream = System.out;

    public PrintStream getStream() {
        return stream;
    }

    public void setStream(PrintStream stream) {
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    @Override
    public void printLine(Object str) {
        stream.println(str);
    }
}
```

**`Test`**

```
import com.dtos.AccountDTO;
import com.dtos.ClientDTO;
import com.services.ClientService;
import com.view.io.Reader;
import com.view.io.Writer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertAll;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.notNull;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.atLeast;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class ClientViewImplTest {
    private Writer writer;
    private Reader reader;
    private ClientService clientService;
    private ClientViewImpl clientView;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        writer = mock(Writer.class);
        reader = mock(Reader.class);
        clientService = mock(ClientService.class);
        clientView = new ClientViewImpl(writer, reader, clientService);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Test
    void displayAllClientsInfo() throws ParseException {
        // Given
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd.MM.yyyy");
        List<ClientDTO> clients = new ArrayList<>();
        clients.add(new ClientDTO(1L, "John Smith", "client@example.com", Arrays.asList(
                new AccountDTO(10L, "JSmith1", "zzwvp0d9", df.parse("10:15:30 20.10.2017")),
                new AccountDTO(20L, "JSmith2", "mhjnbgfv", df.parse("10:15:30 5.5.2017")),
                new AccountDTO(30L, "JSmith3", "ytersds1", df.parse("15:00:30 12.10.2017"))
        )));
        clients.add(new ClientDTO(2L, "Jack Black", "jack@example.com", new ArrayList<>()));
        when(clientService.getAllClients()).thenReturn(clients);
        ArgumentCaptor<Object> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Object.class);
        // When
        clientView.displayAllClientsInfo();
        // Then
        verify(writer, atLeast(1)).printLine(argument.capture());
        List outputList = argument.getAllValues();

        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(2000);
        for (Object sb : outputList) {
            str.append(sb); // here we got empty strings in case sb type's is StringBuilder
        }

        String output = str.toString();
        assertAll(
                // Client
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains(Long.toString(1))),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("client@example.com")),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("John Smith")),
                // Accounts
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains(Long.toString(10))),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("JSmith1")),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("zzwvp0d9")),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains(df.parse("10:15:30 20.10.2017").toString())),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains(Long.toString(20))),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("JSmith2")),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("mhjnbgfv")),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains(df.parse("10:15:30 5.5.2017").toString())),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains(Long.toString(30))),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("JSmith3")),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("ytersds1")),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains(df.parse("15:00:30 12.10.2017").toString())),
                // Client
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains(Long.toString(2))),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("jack@example.com")),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("Jack Black"))
        );
    }
}
```

Method under test **`clientView.displayAllClientsInfo()`**

```
public void displayAllClientsInfo() {
    final Collection<ClientDTO> clients = clientService.getAllClients();
    if (clients != null && clients.size() > 0) {
        writer.printLine(StringUtils.center("Clients", 55) + StringUtils.center("Accounts", 85));
        writer.printLine(StringUtils.repeat("-", 140));
        String columnsNames = String.format("%1$5s%2$25s%3$27s%4$3s%5$30s%6$25s%7$25s", "id", "e-mail", "name |",
                "id", "created", "login", "password");
        writer.printLine(columnsNames);
        writer.printLine(StringUtils.repeat("=", 140));
        StringBuilder clientInfo = new StringBuilder();
        for (ClientDTO client : clients) {
            clientInfo.append(String.format("%1$5d%2$25s%3$25s |", client.getId(), client.getEmail(),
                    client.getName()));
            writer.printLine(clientInfo);
            clientInfo.delete(0, clientInfo.length());
            List<AccountDTO> accounts = client.getAccounts();
            if (accounts != null && accounts.size() > 0) {
                for (AccountDTO ac : accounts) {
                    clientInfo.append(String.format("%1$60d%2$30s%3$25s%4$25s", ac.getId(), ac.getCreated(), ac.getLogin(),
                            ac.getPassword()));
                    clientInfo.setCharAt(56, '|');
                    writer.printLine(clientInfo);
                    clientInfo.delete(0, clientInfo.length());
                }
            }
            clientInfo.delete(0, clientInfo.length());
            writer.printLine(StringUtils.repeat("-", 140));
        }
    } else {
        writer.printLine("No data to display.");
        log.info("No data to display.");
    }
}
```

---

[image: problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `StringBuilder` sets `count` to 0 rather than re-allocating or clearing its internal `char[]` array. This is what happened somewhere in the process, it is not any corruption or inconsistency.

You captured some `StringBuilder` objects by the `ArgumentCaptor`. What the captor does is, it takes the argument that is provided to `System.out.println(Object)` call. In that call, `toString()` method is called on the object implicitly, but the capture takes the `StringBuilder` itself, which is then emptied. As @Sormuras mentioned, the `delete` method called on the builder is what caused the zero count.

Solution? Well, maybe call `toString()` explicitly in `ClientView.displayAllClientsInfo()`, making an actual `String` out of the `StringBuilder`. String builder is only there to build a String, the problem is that thanks to the captor, you are still using it after its lifecycle pretty much ended already.

Also, the use of `StringBuilder` inside `displayAllClientsInfo` method is pretty much pointless, you barely use any of its features at all, I'd just stick to the `String.format` alone.

Comment: _"You can set the length to 0"_ – Do you believe that it did `ArgumentCaptor.capture()`? I have too little knowledge to check this out.

Comment: It shouldn't and I admit this situation is quite weird. Not sure where it happened, but I guess debugging should help you find where it happened. I see nothing like setLength(0) in your code, and I wonder what could access the StringBuilder like that.

Comment: It would be great if you could start debugging yourself. I'm just confused in this jungle :) If missed some required information, I will add.

Comment: I don't have your whole project with me, I can't debug it. I don't have the ClientView class, Writer, Reader, etc. But I think I found it by reading the code.

Comment: _"the problem is that thanks to the captor, you are still using it after its lifecycle pretty much ended already"_ – Thanks for the clarification, You're right. I'll think on a solution.

Comment: I also added a mention on the use of `StringBuilder` in the tested method. It makes no sense there, pretty much, and it could be removed.

Comment: I used StringBuilder because want call `setCharAt`. It may be better to collect all output in a StringBuilder and then call `writer.printLine`? Or I can create post on SO.CodeReview and we will continue...

Comment: Maybe you have something to add. [codereview.se](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/178776/unit-testing-of-presentation-layer)

Comment: Well, the most important thing is to capture an actual String. To do that, even passing `clientInfo.toString()` to the writer is enough. I just find the usage of StringBuilder quite weird since you don't really do much building, doing most of it in `String.format(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one of your `clientInfo.delete(0, clientInfo.length());` sets the length to 0 after it built the expected string content.

Comment: So why when I run `displayAllClientsInfo()` it works fine? (displays all the information as required). I'm a little out debugging and noticed exception in Mockito `Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InterceptedInvocation.toString()`. I guess I stumbled upon a bug.

Comment: You are right. I checked this by replacing `clientInfo.delete(0, clientInfo.length());` with `clientInfo = new StringBuilder();`. And it works (of course it isn't the solution). In any case +1